Python process not spawning off
Following the reference here: Python spawn off a child subprocess, detach, and exit
I tried to implement a functionality which runs a shell but it does not spawns off.
def job_run(command):
    try:
        #os.system(command)
        #subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True)
        cmds=shlex.split(command)
        p=subprocess.Popen(cmds, start_new_session=True)
        return "Success", f">>> Output of the command: ${command}"
    except Exception as e:
        return "Failure", f"??? An error occured: {e}"

command=f"nohup ./run.sh > runLog/nohup.out &"
        result, output = job_run(command)

Result of this code running:
monitoring]$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

It does not completely exits, i have to manually hit multiple enters to come out of the script execution.
How can I handle this?

I don't know what completely exits means (can something exit incompletely?), but the output you posted, shows, that at least the nohup command was executed, from which I would conclude that run.sh was started. If you put a print(result) command after the job_run line, what do you see?

You're not passing shell=True so the shell features you are trying to use ( nohup, redirection, background operation) will not work.
def job_run(command):
    return subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, start_new_session=True)

command=f"nohup ./run.sh > runLog/nohup.out"
background_process = job_run(command)

Popen already runs in the background, so I removed the & too. If the Popen call succeeded, that obviously only tells you whether the process started properly, and you will need to wait on the process, so I peeled off the exception handler too, and made it return the process object which you will need to manage yourself.

Tried this way as well but still it hungs on nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout

Not sure what you mean by "hungs", it will output the string when you start the job but the process runs in the background. (The English verb is "to hang"; the past participle is "hung", as in "I hang until I have hung long enough")

Brief demo: https://ideone.com/9IZ7j6
